GitHub Action workflow to build and publish Angular 18 app to GitHub Pages fails to deploy
I'm setting up custom GitHub Action workflow to publish Angular app to GitHub Pages. The workflow runs without errors but the result is 404 page.
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# Sets permissions of the GITHUB_TOKEN to allow deployment to GitHub Pages
permissions:
  contents: write
  pages: write
  id-token: write


jobs:

  build:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [18.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      #    - name: SonarQube Backend Scan
      #      uses: kitabisa/sonarqube-action@v1.2.1

      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: 'npm'
          cache-dependency-path: package-lock.json

      - name: Install Dependencies
        working-directory: .
        run: npm install

      - name: Build
        working-directory: .
        run: npm run build --if-present

      #    - name: Test
      #      working-directory: src/main/frontend
      #      run: npm test

      - name: Setup Pages
        uses: actions/configure-pages@v3
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v2
        with:
          # Upload entire repository
          path: './dist/'

      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v2

Source code
The log:
2024-06-30T11:36:50.4480678Z Current runner version: '2.317.0'
2024-06-30T11:36:50.4502547Z ##[group]Operating System
2024-06-30T11:36:50.4503178Z Ubuntu
2024-06-30T11:36:50.4503612Z 22.04.4
2024-06-30T11:36:50.4503966Z LTS
2024-06-30T11:36:50.4504302Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-30T11:36:50.4504710Z ##[group]Runner Image
2024-06-30T11:36:50.4505157Z Image: ubuntu-22.04
2024-06-30T11:36:50.4505561Z Version: 20240624.1.0
2024-06-30T11:36:50.4506586Z Included Software: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/ubuntu22/20240624.1/images/ubuntu/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md
2024-06-30T11:36:50.4508006Z Image Release: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/releases/tag/ubuntu22%2F20240624.1
2024-06-30T11:36:50.4508851Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-30T11:36:50.4509315Z ##[group]Runner Image Provisioner
2024-06-30T11:36:50.4509757Z 2.0.370.1
2024-06-30T11:36:50.4510094Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-30T11:36:50.4511107Z ##[group]GITHUB_TOKEN Permissions
2024-06-30T11:36:50.4512614Z Contents: write
2024-06-30T11:36:50.4513183Z Metadata: read
2024-06-30T11:36:50.4513721Z Pages: write
2024-06-30T11:36:50.4514270Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-30T11:36:50.4517372Z Secret source: Actions
2024-06-30T11:36:50.4517966Z Prepare workflow directory
2024-06-30T11:36:50.5129035Z Prepare all required actions
2024-06-30T11:36:50.5293218Z Getting action download info
2024-06-30T11:36:50.7613266Z Download action repository 'actions/checkout@v3' (SHA:f43a0e5ff2bd294095638e18286ca9a3d1956744)
2024-06-30T11:36:50.8617345Z Download action repository 'actions/setup-node@v3' (SHA:1a4442cacd436585916779262731d5b162bc6ec7)
2024-06-30T11:36:50.9560422Z Download action repository 'actions/configure-pages@v3' (SHA:b8130d9ab958b325bbde9786d62f2c97a9885a0e)
2024-06-30T11:36:51.5029387Z Download action repository 'actions/upload-pages-artifact@v2' (SHA:a753861a5debcf57bf8b404356158c8e1e33150c)
2024-06-30T11:36:51.8521564Z Download action repository 'actions/deploy-pages@v2' (SHA:de14547edc9944350dc0481aa5b7afb08e75f254)
2024-06-30T11:36:52.4578463Z Getting action download info
2024-06-30T11:36:52.6030466Z Download action repository 'actions/upload-artifact@v3' (SHA:a8a3f3ad30e3422c9c7b888a15615d19a852ae32)
2024-06-30T11:36:52.6643240Z Complete job name: build (18.x)
2024-06-30T11:36:52.7434239Z ##[group]Run actions/checkout@v3
2024-06-30T11:36:52.7434751Z with:
2024-06-30T11:36:52.7435112Z   repository: mr-olufsen/webapp
2024-06-30T11:36:52.7435787Z   token: ***
2024-06-30T11:36:52.7436091Z   ssh-strict: true
2024-06-30T11:36:52.7436476Z   persist-credentials: true
2024-06-30T11:36:52.7436941Z   clean: true
2024-06-30T11:36:52.7437249Z   sparse-checkout-cone-mode: true
2024-06-30T11:36:52.7437680Z   fetch-depth: 1
2024-06-30T11:36:52.7438070Z   fetch-tags: false
2024-06-30T11:36:52.7438365Z   lfs: false
2024-06-30T11:36:52.7438689Z   submodules: false
2024-06-30T11:36:52.7439088Z   set-safe-directory: true
2024-06-30T11:36:52.7439414Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9169976Z Syncing repository: mr-olufsen/webapp
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9171872Z ##[group]Getting Git version info
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9172544Z Working directory is '/home/runner/work/webapp/webapp'
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9173665Z [command]/usr/bin/git version
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9190676Z git version 2.45.2
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9214752Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9242508Z Temporarily overriding HOME='/home/runner/work/_temp/fccdb74a-78c9-4d73-93a3-30acb3d24328' before making global git config changes
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9243831Z Adding repository directory to the temporary git global config as a safe directory
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9247596Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --global --add safe.directory /home/runner/work/webapp/webapp
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9292452Z Deleting the contents of '/home/runner/work/webapp/webapp'
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9297214Z ##[group]Initializing the repository
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9301122Z [command]/usr/bin/git init /home/runner/work/webapp/webapp
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9380904Z hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default branch name
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9384633Z hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use in all
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9386327Z hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9387539Z hint:
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9388406Z hint:  git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9389273Z hint:
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9390407Z hint: Names commonly chosen instead of 'master' are 'main', 'trunk' and
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9391817Z hint: 'development'. The just-created branch can be renamed via this command:
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9392806Z hint:
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9393509Z hint:  git branch -m <name>
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9394479Z Initialized empty Git repository in /home/runner/work/webapp/webapp/.git/
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9396967Z [command]/usr/bin/git remote add origin https://github.com/mr-olufsen/webapp
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9435898Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9436932Z ##[group]Disabling automatic garbage collection
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9440202Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --local gc.auto 0
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9479015Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9481374Z ##[group]Setting up auth
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9486549Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --local --name-only --get-regexp core\.sshCommand
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9524169Z [command]/usr/bin/git submodule foreach --recursive sh -c "git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'core\.sshCommand' && git config --local --unset-all 'core.sshCommand' || :"
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9821422Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --local --name-only --get-regexp http\.https\:\/\/github\.com\/\.extraheader
2024-06-30T11:36:52.9855687Z [command]/usr/bin/git submodule foreach --recursive sh -c "git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'http\.https\:\/\/github\.com\/\.extraheader' && git config --local --unset-all 'http.https://github.com/.extraheader' || :"
2024-06-30T11:36:53.0096408Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --local http.https://github.com/.extraheader AUTHORIZATION: basic ***
2024-06-30T11:36:53.0137272Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-30T11:36:53.0138409Z ##[group]Fetching the repository
2024-06-30T11:36:53.0147731Z [command]/usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 fetch --no-tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules --depth=1 origin +b9dcc6be482e76ea5b415e0abc8e02a610c5625a:refs/remotes/origin/main     
2024-06-30T11:36:53.4225271Z From https://github.com/mr-olufsen/webapp
2024-06-30T11:36:53.4226285Z  * [new ref]         b9dcc6be482e76ea5b415e0abc8e02a610c5625a -> origin/main
2024-06-30T11:36:53.4251128Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-30T11:36:53.4252246Z ##[group]Determining the checkout info
2024-06-30T11:36:53.4254027Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-30T11:36:53.4255115Z ##[group]Checking out the ref
2024-06-30T11:36:53.4260131Z [command]/usr/bin/git checkout --progress --force -B main refs/remotes/origin/main
2024-06-30T11:36:53.4369367Z Switched to a new branch 'main'
2024-06-30T11:36:53.4372950Z branch 'main' set up to track 'origin/main'.
2024-06-30T11:36:53.4377581Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-30T11:36:53.4420629Z [command]/usr/bin/git log -1 --format='%H'
2024-06-30T11:36:53.4450877Z 'b9dcc6be482e76ea5b415e0abc8e02a610c5625a'
2024-06-30T11:36:53.4761386Z ##[group]Run actions/setup-node@v3
2024-06-30T11:36:53.4761932Z with:
2024-06-30T11:36:53.4762233Z   node-version: 18.x
2024-06-30T11:36:53.4762583Z   cache: npm
2024-06-30T11:36:53.4763021Z   cache-dependency-path: package-lock.json
2024-06-30T11:36:53.4763497Z   always-auth: false
2024-06-30T11:36:53.4763813Z   check-latest: false
2024-06-30T11:36:53.4764469Z   token: ***
2024-06-30T11:36:53.4764944Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-30T11:36:53.6806613Z Found in cache @ /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.20.3/x64
2024-06-30T11:36:53.6816649Z ##[group]Environment details
2024-06-30T11:36:54.0107017Z node: v18.20.3
2024-06-30T11:36:54.0107681Z npm: 10.7.0
2024-06-30T11:36:54.0108122Z yarn: 1.22.22
2024-06-30T11:36:54.0109256Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-30T11:36:54.0121351Z [command]/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.20.3/x64/bin/npm config get cache
2024-06-30T11:36:54.1389834Z /home/runner/.npm
2024-06-30T11:36:54.4971612Z npm cache is not found
2024-06-30T11:36:54.5105275Z ##[group]Run npm install
2024-06-30T11:36:54.5105741Z [36;1mnpm install[0m
2024-06-30T11:36:54.5219560Z shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
2024-06-30T11:36:54.5219979Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-30T11:36:58.0592783Z npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
2024-06-30T11:36:58.8565805Z npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
2024-06-30T11:36:59.0102416Z npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
2024-06-30T11:37:05.7494759Z 
2024-06-30T11:37:05.7495869Z added 990 packages, and audited 991 packages in 11s
2024-06-30T11:37:05.7496607Z 
2024-06-30T11:37:05.7497159Z 134 packages are looking for funding
2024-06-30T11:37:05.7498023Z   run `npm fund` for details
2024-06-30T11:37:05.7509398Z 
2024-06-30T11:37:05.7510371Z found 0 vulnerabilities
2024-06-30T11:37:05.7852705Z ##[group]Run npm run build --if-present
2024-06-30T11:37:05.7853333Z [36;1mnpm run build --if-present[0m
2024-06-30T11:37:05.7913974Z shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
2024-06-30T11:37:05.7914335Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-30T11:37:05.9187512Z 
2024-06-30T11:37:05.9188168Z > webapp@0.0.0 build
2024-06-30T11:37:05.9189005Z > ng build
2024-06-30T11:37:05.9191502Z 
2024-06-30T11:37:06.5229059Z - Building...
2024-06-30T11:37:06.5229548Z 
2024-06-30T11:37:16.3064680Z Initial chunk files   | Names         |  Raw size | Estimated transfer size
2024-06-30T11:37:16.3066941Z main-ILM3M4T7.js      | main          | 936.14 kB |               185.83 kB
2024-06-30T11:37:16.3068782Z styles-BD2XYORA.css   | styles        | 303.93 kB |                29.55 kB
2024-06-30T11:37:16.3070727Z scripts-EEEIPNC3.js   | scripts       |  80.34 kB |                21.56 kB
2024-06-30T11:37:16.3100311Z polyfills-6EAL64PA.js | polyfills     |  34.23 kB |                11.13 kB
2024-06-30T11:37:16.3101521Z 
2024-06-30T11:37:16.3102472Z                       | Initial total |   1.35 MB |               248.06 kB
2024-06-30T11:37:16.3103412Z 
2024-06-30T11:37:16.3104086Z Output location: /home/runner/work/webapp/webapp/dist/webapp
2024-06-30T11:37:16.3104870Z 
2024-06-30T11:37:16.3106466Z ▲ [WARNING] 2 rules skipped due to selector errors:
2024-06-30T11:37:16.3107779Z   .form-floating>~label -> Did not expect successive traversals.
2024-06-30T11:37:16.3109118Z   .form-floating>~label -> Did not expect successive traversals.
2024-06-30T11:37:16.3110385Z Application bundle generation complete. [9.782 seconds]
2024-06-30T11:37:16.3111291Z 
2024-06-30T11:37:16.3112017Z 
2024-06-30T11:37:16.3112034Z 
2024-06-30T11:37:16.3816259Z ##[group]Run actions/configure-pages@v3
2024-06-30T11:37:16.3816742Z with:
2024-06-30T11:37:16.3817154Z   token: ***
2024-06-30T11:37:16.3817585Z   enablement: false
2024-06-30T11:37:16.3817944Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-30T11:37:16.6851825Z ##[group]Run actions/upload-pages-artifact@v2
2024-06-30T11:37:16.6852419Z with:
2024-06-30T11:37:16.6852730Z   path: ./dist/
2024-06-30T11:37:16.6853050Z   name: github-pages
2024-06-30T11:37:16.6853461Z   retention-days: 1
2024-06-30T11:37:16.6853801Z env:
2024-06-30T11:37:16.6854077Z   GITHUB_PAGES: true
2024-06-30T11:37:16.6854476Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7050574Z ##[group]Run tar \
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7051015Z [36;1mtar \[0m
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7051372Z [36;1m  --dereference --hard-dereference \[0m
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7051881Z [36;1m  --directory "$INPUT_PATH" \[0m
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7052422Z [36;1m  -cvf "$RUNNER_TEMP/artifact.tar" \[0m
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7052833Z [36;1m  --exclude=.git \[0m
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7053231Z [36;1m  --exclude=.github \[0m
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7053679Z [36;1m  .[0m
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7085658Z shell: /usr/bin/sh -e {0}
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7086171Z env:
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7086475Z   GITHUB_PAGES: true
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7087016Z   INPUT_PATH: ./dist/
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7087333Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7150001Z ./
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7150658Z ./webapp/
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7151278Z ./webapp/3rdpartylicenses.txt
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7151957Z ./webapp/browser/
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7152500Z ./webapp/browser/main-ILM3M4T7.js
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7165074Z ./webapp/browser/polyfills-6EAL64PA.js
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7166109Z ./webapp/browser/styles-BD2XYORA.css
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7170170Z ./webapp/browser/index.html
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7171228Z ./webapp/browser/scripts-EEEIPNC3.js
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7172542Z ./webapp/browser/favicon.ico
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7227826Z ##[group]Run actions/upload-artifact@v3
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7228352Z with:
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7228620Z   name: github-pages
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7229014Z   path: /home/runner/work/_temp/artifact.tar
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7229529Z   retention-days: 1
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7229841Z   if-no-files-found: error
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7230200Z env:
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7230576Z   GITHUB_PAGES: true
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7230877Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7850430Z With the provided path, there will be 1 file uploaded
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7852412Z Starting artifact upload
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7855131Z For more detailed logs during the artifact upload process, enable step-debugging: https://docs.github.com/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/enabling-debug-logging#enabling-step-debug-logging
2024-06-30T11:37:16.7856974Z Artifact name is valid!
2024-06-30T11:37:17.1225350Z Container for artifact "github-pages" successfully created. Starting upload of file(s)
2024-06-30T11:37:17.9074187Z Total size of all the files uploaded is 320238 bytes
2024-06-30T11:37:17.9075570Z File upload process has finished. Finalizing the artifact upload
2024-06-30T11:37:18.2597926Z Artifact has been finalized. All files have been successfully uploaded!
2024-06-30T11:37:18.2598746Z 
2024-06-30T11:37:18.2599495Z The raw size of all the files that were specified for upload is 1454080 bytes
2024-06-30T11:37:18.2604072Z The size of all the files that were uploaded is 320238 bytes. This takes into account any gzip compression used to reduce the upload size, time and storage
2024-06-30T11:37:18.2605384Z 
2024-06-30T11:37:18.2609222Z Note: The size of downloaded zips can differ significantly from the reported size. For more information see: https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact#zipped-artifact-downloads 
2024-06-30T11:37:18.2621672Z 
2024-06-30T11:37:18.2622291Z Artifact github-pages has been successfully uploaded!
2024-06-30T11:37:18.2718342Z ##[group]Run actions/deploy-pages@v2
2024-06-30T11:37:18.2718792Z with:
2024-06-30T11:37:18.2719324Z   token: ***
2024-06-30T11:37:18.2719667Z   timeout: 600000
2024-06-30T11:37:18.2719956Z   error_count: 10
2024-06-30T11:37:18.2720378Z   reporting_interval: 5000
2024-06-30T11:37:18.2720725Z   artifact_name: github-pages
2024-06-30T11:37:18.2721097Z   preview: false
2024-06-30T11:37:18.2721505Z env:
2024-06-30T11:37:18.2721766Z   GITHUB_PAGES: true
2024-06-30T11:37:18.2722099Z ##[endgroup]
2024-06-30T11:37:18.6961899Z Artifact exchange URL: https://pipelinesghubeus5.actions.githubusercontent.com/8hWRsG9Mf9GU1lu6fo8MHPQDh0xYGMqFAHEtD8DKwqiD7u4RUQ/_apis/pipelines/workflows/9731679898/artifacts?api-version=6.0-preview
2024-06-30T11:37:18.9956105Z Creating Pages deployment with payload:
2024-06-30T11:37:18.9957395Z {
2024-06-30T11:37:18.9960493Z    "artifact_url": "https://pipelinesghubeus5.actions.githubusercontent.com/8hWRsG9Mf9GU1lu6fo8MHPQDh0xYGMqFAHEtD8DKwqiD7u4RUQ/_apis/pipelines/1/runs/2/artifacts?artifactName=github-pages&%24expand=SignedContent",
2024-06-30T11:37:18.9963127Z    "pages_build_version": "b9dcc6be482e76ea5b415e0abc8e02a610c5625a",
2024-06-30T11:37:19.0029165Z    "oidc_token": "***"
2024-06-30T11:37:19.0029615Z }
2024-06-30T11:37:19.3222054Z Created deployment for b9dcc6be482e76ea5b415e0abc8e02a610c5625a, ID: b9dcc6be482e76ea5b415e0abc8e02a610c5625a
2024-06-30T11:37:24.3310379Z Getting Pages deployment status...
2024-06-30T11:37:24.5058783Z Reported success!
2024-06-30T11:37:24.5193979Z Post job cleanup.
2024-06-30T11:37:24.6930012Z [command]/usr/bin/tar --posix -cf cache.tzst --exclude cache.tzst -P -C /home/runner/work/webapp/webapp --files-from manifest.txt --use-compress-program zstdmt
2024-06-30T11:37:28.6734828Z Cache Size: ~80 MB (83667971 B)
2024-06-30T11:37:29.0175349Z Cache saved successfully
2024-06-30T11:37:29.0345864Z Cache saved with the key: node-cache-Linux-npm-823668ae3e95ab9d5d925a6195b0ce8a870fce76484d9a3ae1b248a8d9d87282
2024-06-30T11:37:29.0498110Z Post job cleanup.
2024-06-30T11:37:29.1306484Z [command]/usr/bin/git version
2024-06-30T11:37:29.1350137Z git version 2.45.2
2024-06-30T11:37:29.1389615Z Temporarily overriding HOME='/home/runner/work/_temp/424a3247-fd4e-44cb-b020-8088468792a8' before making global git config changes
2024-06-30T11:37:29.1391254Z Adding repository directory to the temporary git global config as a safe directory
2024-06-30T11:37:29.1395477Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --global --add safe.directory /home/runner/work/webapp/webapp
2024-06-30T11:37:29.1435960Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --local --name-only --get-regexp core\.sshCommand
2024-06-30T11:37:29.1474004Z [command]/usr/bin/git submodule foreach --recursive sh -c "git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'core\.sshCommand' && git config --local --unset-all 'core.sshCommand' || :"
2024-06-30T11:37:29.1722451Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --local --name-only --get-regexp http\.https\:\/\/github\.com\/\.extraheader
2024-06-30T11:37:29.1751145Z http.https://github.com/.extraheader
2024-06-30T11:37:29.1763114Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --local --unset-all http.https://github.com/.extraheader
2024-06-30T11:37:29.1799828Z [command]/usr/bin/git submodule foreach --recursive sh -c "git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'http\.https\:\/\/github\.com\/\.extraheader' && git config --local --unset-all 'http.https://github.com/.extraheader' || :"
2024-06-30T11:37:29.2250169Z Evaluate and set environment url
2024-06-30T11:37:29.2253764Z Evaluated environment url: https://mr-olufsen.github.io/webapp/
2024-06-30T11:37:29.2254621Z Cleaning up orphan processes

Config:


Checking your repository, there is not minimal required file for a webiste:

index.html


Verify github page setup
Just to test if your github page is well configured,

At the root push an index.html with any content
Wait some  seconds and or check the github action until it finish.
Check if the 404 error gone

If this  "manually" test doesn't work, even less will work your real github action
How github pages works
As a summary :

Repository should contain the index.html at the root or in folder called docs which is mandatory
Then go to settings and select the branch and the root / or the /docs folder


dist folder
Review the publish section of your github action.

No matter how it works actions/configure-pages@v3, the final github repository should have the index.html, jsj, css, etc which is the content of you angular build in dist folder
Check this in which a coverage page is deployed with github actions
